# jquery function not registering changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script in my django project that reads checkboxes and then submits them to a function when clicked. My problem is that this only works when I reload my page. is it possible to have the jquery script "listening" allt the time to the checkboxes?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vals = [];
  $.each($("input[name='checkb']:checked"), function() {
    vals.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });  
  console.log('calling function:', vals)
  
  $('.print').click(function() {
    console.log('print:', vals)
    $.get('eprint/ticked/', {
      marked: vals
    })
  })
  
  $('.delete').click(function() {
    console.log('delete:', vals)
    $.get('edelete/ticked/', {
      marked: vals
    })
  });
});
```

```html
{% for l in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id={{l.pk}} name="checkb"></label>
        <form>
```

Comment: if you are created DOM elements dynamically you need to listen to events globally. like listen to the children of body element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you require would be to add a `change` event handler to the checkboxes so that you can update the `vals` variable whenever the user checks or unchecks a box.

However, I'd suggest instead that you simply create a function which reads the values at the point they are required in the `.print` and `.delete` click handlers. This avoids any unnecessary global variables, and avoids the need to maintain an array as you're reading the DOM exactly at the point the action occurs. Try this:

```js
let getValues = () => $("input[name='checkb']:checked").map((i, el) => el.value.trim()).get();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.print').on('click', () => {
    $.get('eprint/ticked/', {
      marked: getValues()
    });
  });
  
  $('.delete').on('click', () => {
    $.get('edelete/ticked/', {
      marked: getValues()
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks. I still need the pk values, instead of a list of "on". But I think I can fix that

Comment: Still an open question, how do I get the actual id of the checkboxes?

Comment: In the `map()` handler change `el.value` to `el.id`